# Moving to ZIG ZAG merge versus optimal indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, objectify

My application currently defines all optimal indexes needed. But slowly I start suffering from the exploding indexes problem, so I want to switch my strategy and start using "zig-zag" merge as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection).

My entity `Contact` has 3 sort orders :

- `lastModified` ASC
- `fullNameUpperCase` ASC + DESC

It has 4 filters :

- `contactProfile`
- `contactStatus`
- `contactType`
- `searchFields` (inequality query to emulate 'startsWith...')

searchFields is a special case,because I use it to emulate 'startswith' like this

```
 query = query.filter("searchFields >= ", criteria.getSearchString().toUpperCase());
 query = query.filter("searchFields <= ", criteria.getSearchString().toUpperCase() + "\ufffd");
```

Following the explanations in the article, I need to define

```
 (number of filters + 1) * (number of orders) = 5 * 3 = 15.
```

- **My main problem!** :

The new definitions below seem to work on the development server but **not the first time**. The first time it should do new combination of zigzag merge, the devserver still throws the DatastoreNeedIndexException. Repeating the same query for a second time, the query runs and returns expected results. This also happens when paging through the results. The first time I query the next page, exception is thrown. Repeating works. Anybody has seen this behaviour too ? Is this devserver problem or am I missing something ? Or is this index-building that is incomplete at first maybe... e.g. the devserver complains this is missing as an index the first time I combine these filters :

```
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="status" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Here are the new index definitions for entity Contact :

```
<!-- SORT ORDERS -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: SEARCHFIELDS -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTSTATUS -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTTYPE -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTPROFILE -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that it does not work was fixed after I moved the sort order to being the last property of the in the combined indexes.

So for instance

```
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

had to become.

```
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

so the last property is the sort order.

Secondly, the seachFields must be considered as sort orders and I have to make the combination. The indexes now become 
5 sort orders :

- lastModified ASC
- fullNameUpperCase ASC + DESC
- searchFields ASC + DESC

3 filters :

- contactProfile
- contactStatus
- contactType

  (number of filters + 1) * (number of orders) = 4 * 5 = 20 indexes.

Here's the fully functional list :

```
<!-- SORT ORDERS -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="searchFields" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTSTATUS -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="status" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTTYPE -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactType" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<!-- FILTER: CONTACTPROFILE -->
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
    <property name="fullNameUpperCase" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
    <property name="lastModified" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="contactProfile" direction="asc" />
    <property name="searchFields" direction="desc" />
</datastore-index>
```

PS : I removed the additional questions on how to migrate a production environment to new indexes, I will post a new question in case needed;

Comment: Hey, could you let me know how you migrated production env to new indices?

Comment: @morpheus Just add the required indexes for zigzag merge, wait for them to build. Later on, you can remove the old, unused indexes using "appcfg vacuum_indexes"